# Human Height Dropdown for Rails

Tags: ruby, plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I need a dropdown of human heights, for example 5'2, 5'3, 5'4, etc. Preferably something like 4'0 to 8'0. Is there a gem or plugin? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you'd store it in inches anyway, so you could generate your `@heights` to pass to options_from_collection_for_select like:

```
(56..112).to_a.map { |inch| { id: inch.to_s, name: (inch/12).floor.to_s+'\''+(inch%12).to_s } }
```

Perhaps with the inch to string conversion broken out into a helper method.

Comment: Just one tiny correction, you'll want to divide by 12 not 14.

Comment: @PaulPettengill Er, good point. I think I must have been thinking pounds in a stone. Edited.

Comment: Just got done working on a huge project where this helped out a ton! Thanks so much!

Comment: Should I divide it by 12 or 14? It's a system to be used in Canada. Sorry I know this is old. 
@PaulPettengill

Comment: @JoãoPauloMotta Its 12.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way,
but you can try some thing like this

```
@heights = (4..7).to_a.collect{|o| 0.upto(11).to_a.collect{|k| ["#{o.to_s+'\'' + k.to_s}",o.to_s + k.to_s]}}.inject([]){|s,v| s | v}
```

OR better,

```
@heights = (4..7).to_a.collect{|o| 0.upto(11).to_a.collect{|k| ["#{o.to_s+'\'' + k.to_s}",o.to_s + k.to_s]}}.flatten(1)
```

this shall give a structure like,

```
[["4'0", "40"], ["4'1", "41"], ["4'2", "42"], ["4'3", "43"], ["4'4", "44"]] # and so on..
```

Now, to prepare this structure for select options, you can use:

```
@heights.map { |name, id| OpenStruct.new(:value => id, :name => name) }
```

This will give a name and value pair for each height element, that can be used for making options for select tag

You may need to include OpenStruct, so use

```
require 'ostruct'
```

Putting this in select tag:

```
<%= select_tag "Height", options_from_collection_for_select(@heights,'value','name'), html_options = { :onChange=> "height_changed();"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a good gem for human height 
https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/height

write a helper

```
def height
(121..244).to_a.collect{|k| ["#{Height.new(k).to_s(:default, :metric)}","#{Height.new(k).to_s(:default, :imperial)}","#{Height.new(k).feet}"]}
end
```

output

```
[["1m 21cm", "4 ft 0 in", "4"], ["1m 22cm", "4 ft 0 in", "4"], ["1m 23cm", "4 ft 0 in", "4"], ["1m 24cm", "4 ft 1 in", "4.08"]
```

Use the method in the template

```
<%= f.input :how_tall_are_you, label: "How tall are you ? (in feet  and Cm)", collection: height.map { |cm, inc, value| ["#{cm} - #{inc}", "#{value}"] }  ,prompt: "-Please select one-",input_html: { class: 'form-control input-lg', required: true} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Colin's answer got me part of the way there:

```
<%=
  n.select :height, 
  options_for_select((36..96).to_a.map { |inch| 
    { 
      id: inch.to_s, 
      name: (inch/12).floor.to_s+'\''+(inch%12).to_s+'"' 
    }
  }),
  {},
  id: 'height' 
%>
```

In the view, the dropdown menu displayed like this:

[image: height dropdown]

The HTML rendered like this:

```
<select id="height" name="height_select">
<option value="{:id=>&quot;36&quot;, :name=>&quot;3'0\&quot;&quot;}">{:id=&gt;"36", :name=&gt;"3'0\""}</option>
<option value="{:id=>&quot;37&quot;, :name=>&quot;3'1\&quot;&quot;}">{:id=&gt;"37", :name=&gt;"3'1\""}</option>
<option value="{:id=>&quot;38&quot;, :name=>&quot;3'2\&quot;&quot;}">{:id=&gt;"38", :name=&gt;"3'2\""}</option>
....
```

To get it to display the height only, I added a collect and specified what to display (name). I also specified a default value (user_height).

```
<%= 
  n.select :height, 
  options_for_select(
    (36..96).to_a.map { |inch| 
      { 
        id: inch.to_s, 
        name: (inch/12).floor.to_s+'\''+(inch%12).to_s+'"' 
      } 
    }.collect{ |p| 
      [p[:name], 
      p[:id].to_i]
    },
    user_height),
    {},
    id: 'height' 
%>
```

[image: height dropdown leo]

HTML render:

```
<select id="height" name="height_select">
<option value="36">3'0"</option>
<option value="37">3'1"</option>
<option value="38">3'2"</option>
...
<option selected="selected" value="69">5'9"</option>
...
</select>
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but it works!

Here is [some relevant documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).